# Detect phone wake up while app is terminated. -Android

Tags: android, service, android-service

I am trying to detect phone's wake up. I managed to do this while the app is running in background or foreground. However, I need to be able to this while the app is terminated.

In my code, I create a new service and started it in the onCreate method. Here is my code :

Main Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       startService(new Intent(this, ScreenService.class));
   }
}
```

My Service class:

```
public class ScreenService extends Service{

    private BroadcastReceiver sReceiver;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg){
       return null;
    }

    public  int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag, int startIs) {

        IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        sReceiver=new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(sReceiver,filter);
        return  START_STICKY;

   }
}
```

And my Service Handler class:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
        Log.e("Log", "The screen is on.");
    }
    else{
        Log.e("Log", "The screen is off.");
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do to detect phone wakes up while app is terminated?

Comment: you can use WorkManager or FirebaseJobDispatcher ,

Comment: Ah, I got the problem I think.. Some phones do not support the background application I guess.. Because when I change my phone, the code works fine, and I detect the screen on/of while app is closed.

Comment: yes it can be done from settings, even you can restrict apps to use data/other resources in background.